# What is a Summary Autocorrelation Function (SACF)?

Tags: autocorrelation

Seen this in a few papers regarding ACF-based pitch detectors, 
e.g. in

http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/G.Brown/pdf/casareview05.pdf p. 7-8 where they give you the equation for $S(t,τ)$.

but no clear explanation so far on what Summary Autocorrelation Function (SACF) is.

What is it? What are frequency channels $f$? What does it mean to sum across them?

Comment: What are you quoting? Please give a full reference.

Comment: Probably just a straight average of the correlograms across the frequency spectrum.

Comment: So would it be that correlograms are treated as e.g. separate distributions (their values are frequencies) and then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean of the frequencies is taken from both/all of the distributions? So SACF would be about finding the centroid of the sum of the two or more correlograms?